# Odd/Even fancy headers with article class

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, double-sided, article

Using `fancyhdr` and the `book` class, one can set different headers/footers for odd/even pages as

```
\fancyhdr[RO]{foo}
\fancyhdr[LE]{bar}
```

and so on. How can I achieve the same with an `article` class, where things are not two sided?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `article` class defaults to a simple `oneside` document. You can load it with the `twoside` option

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{foo}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{bar}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: That apparently changes the whole geometry of the first two pages: the settings of `\usepackage{geometry}` seem to be ignored there, but honored in the following pages. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @Andyc perhaps you could create a complete minimum working example and post a follow-up question?